# NodeJS: Breaking a large amount of synchronous tasks into async tasks

Tags: node.js, asynchronous

I am processing large amounts of jobs and then writing them into the database. The workflow is that:

1. Read about `100 MB` of data into buffer
2. Loop through the data and then process (sync work) and write to disk (async work)

The problem I am having is that, it will finish looping through all `100 MB` of data and in the meantime queue up all the writing to disk behind the event loop. So, it will first iterate through all the data, and then run the async job.

I would like to break the synchronous task of iterating through the array so that each iteration gets queued as behind the event loop.

```
var lotsOfWorkToBeDone = ['tens of thousands of job', 'tens of thousands of job', 'tens of thousands of job', 'tens of thousands of job', 'tens of thousands of job', 'tens of thousands of job', 'tens of thousands of job']

while (true) {
  var job = lotsOfWorkToBeDone.pop()
  if (!job) {
    break
  }
  var syncResult = syncWork(job)
  asyncWork(syncResult)
}

function syncWork(job) {
  console.log('sync work:', job)
  return 'Sync Result of ' + job
};

function asyncWork(syncResult) {
  setTimeout(function() {
    console.log('async work: ', syncResult)
  }, 0)
}


// Desire Outcome
// sync work: tens of thousands of job
// async work: Sync Result of tens of thousands of job
// sync work: tens of thousands of job
// async work: Sync Result of tens of thousands of job
// sync work: tens of thousands of job
// async work: Sync Result of tens of thousands of job
// sync work: tens of thousands of job
// async work: Sync Result of tens of thousands of job
// sync work: tens of thousands of job
// async work: Sync Result of tens of thousands of job
// sync work: tens of thousands of job
// async work: Sync Result of tens of thousands of job
// sync work: tens of thousands of job
// async work: Sync Result of tens of thousands of job

// Actual Outcome
// sync work: tens of thousands of job
// sync work: tens of thousands of job
// sync work: tens of thousands of job
// sync work: tens of thousands of job
// sync work: tens of thousands of job
// sync work: tens of thousands of job
// sync work: tens of thousands of job
// async work: Sync Result of tens of thousands of job
// async work: Sync Result of tens of thousands of job
// async work: Sync Result of tens of thousands of job
// async work: Sync Result of tens of thousands of job
// async work: Sync Result of tens of thousands of job
// async work: Sync Result of tens of thousands of job
// async work: Sync Result of tens of thousands of job
```

Note: The example is simplified version of reality. I don't have an array that I can iterate through. And I have a big buffer and I process until EOF (therefore, the while loop)

Comment: Can't u do a pre job to build an array with the items of the buffer and then u iterate this array with async.foreach?

Comment: Actually, that might be a good idea.

Comment: Yes, I think that is the only solution because it seems that u can't iterate the buffer in a async way, let me know if it works and then I can post an answer

Comment: Ok @fmodos, didn't work. Did I do something wrong? http://justpaste.it/eeuv

Comment: I am in my phone right now and can't do any coding test, check the tutorial http://justinklemm.com/node-js-async-tutorial/ I think the parallel function might solve your problem

Comment: Node is single process, so you can do only one thing at a time, and use only one processor. Have you tried http://nodejs.org/api/child_process.html or http://nodejs.org/api/cluster.html?

Comment: @fmodos have you had a chance to take a look?

Comment: @alumns I took a look at that and unfortunately couldn't get the result expected by you, this is something that got me interested to understand but I am pretty busy with other stuffs, please let me know if you solve it in the future.

Comment: @fmodos I found a solution using async.whilst would you be able to take a look and see if you have any comments? I posted it as an answer

Comment: @alumns that seems to do the work, I had never heard about this whilst function before, did some google but found very low docummentation about it, anyway good job. I voted +1 for finding a solution and posting it :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using async.whilst seems to achieve the desired outcome.

I won't accept my own answer for now as I am interested in what comments people would like to make on this solution. There may be a better solution

```
var async = require('async')
var lotsOfWorkToBeDone = ['tens of thousands of job', 'tens of thousands of job', 'tens of thousands of job', 'tens of thousands of job', 'tens of thousands of job', 'tens of thousands of job', 'tens of thousands of job']

var job;
async.whilst(function() {
  job = lotsOfWorkToBeDone.pop()
  return job
}, function(callback) {
  var syncResult = syncWork(job)
  asyncWork(syncResult, callback)
}, function(err) {
  console.log('error: ', err)
})

function syncWork(job) {
  console.log('sync work:', job)
  return 'Sync Result of ' + job
};

function asyncWork(syncResult, callback) {
  setTimeout(function() {
    console.log('async work: ', syncResult)
    callback()
  }, 0)
}

// sync work: tens of thousands of job
// async work:  Sync Result of tens of thousands of job
// sync work: tens of thousands of job
// async work:  Sync Result of tens of thousands of job
// sync work: tens of thousands of job
// async work:  Sync Result of tens of thousands of job
// sync work: tens of thousands of job
// async work:  Sync Result of tens of thousands of job
// sync work: tens of thousands of job
// async work:  Sync Result of tens of thousands of job
// sync work: tens of thousands of job
// async work:  Sync Result of tens of thousands of job
// sync work: tens of thousands of job
// async work:  Sync Result of tens of thousands of job
```

Answer (score 0):

Consider using streams. Buffering 100 MB sounds like a bad idea. The final code will look something like this:

```
inputStream.pipe(yourTransformStream).pipe(outputStream);
```

all the logic will be implement as [`Transform`](http://nodejs.org/api/stream.html#stream_class_stream_transform_1) stream.

Comment: I certainly have considered that. But because a long list of reasons due to dependencies I actually can't use streams